# Health insurance for American living abroad visiting the USA

Tags: usa, health, insurance

Note: I am an American citizen living in Norway.

As an outdoor person, I plan to do some climbing, hiking etc. while visiting the USA this summer, and I was thinking it may be wise to get some short-term health insurance.

I mostly would like a low deductible emergency coverage, but it seems like temporary insurance plans are fairly expensive due to the general coverage that they offer.

Is there a type of insurance that is specific (or suited) to this scenario?

Comment: Travel insurance?

Answer (score 3):

Since you live in Norway, you might check with Norwegian companies for travel medical insurance.  I think you're more likely to find policies that are short-term and focused on emergency protection than if you try U.S. based health insurance companies.  Travel medical insurance seems like what you want: it covers emergency expenses incurred during the trip.