# Travel insurance for US citizen living abroad visiting US for 5 months

Tags: usa, us-citizens, insurance

I am a US citizen living in Korea since 2007. I will be visiting the US for five months, then returning to Korea. How do I find travel insurance for the period I am in the US?

This question, [Health insurance for American living abroad visiting the USA](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27339/health-insurance-for-american-living-abroad-visiting-the-usa), seems similar but the insurance I need is slightly different:

- high-deductible
- general coverage
- more long-term (I have found [travel insurance that would cover me for up to 45 days](https://www.sevencorners.com/liaison-international).)

My main concern is unforeseen medical care that would be too costly for me to pay for.

It seems most travel insurance companies [exclude US citizens visiting the US to avoid legal complexity](https://www.internationalcitizens.com/blog/international-travel-insurance/us-citizen-travel-insurance-to-the-usa.php):

> ... a US Citizen inside the USA is the domain of domestic insurance,
>   which can be a regulatory nightmare for insurance companies, and thus
>   they simple opt not to get involved.

Two things I am currently investigating are:

- global insurance plans that include the US
- travel insurance from Korean companies

I would be willing to get domestic US health insurance, but most plans require a minimum period of residency before I am eligible.

Comment: We can't really recommend specific carriers here - research the carriers that provide travel medical insurance to travelers from (South?) Korea traveling abroad.  With luck someone does not exclude US citizens.  (I live in Canada and can sell such insurance to US residents in Canada traveling outside Canada, even to the US, so such insurance does exist.)

Comment: Are you concerned about the health insurance aspect of it, eg do you also need ACA ("obamacare") coverage?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: Health insurance is my main concern; I didn't think I needed to worry about ACA, but now I will investigate that, too (part of the reason for this trip is to work in the US). Seems rough to penalize people for not having insurance if no one is willing to insure them...

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Unless the poster is becoming a resident alien, I don't believe he'll qualify for ACA.

Comment: The op is already a citizen, Jim, unless I'm misunderstanding somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider yourself to be moving from a foreign country to the US, you are eligible for "special enrollment period" treatment under the ACA, and can buy health insurance [as described on healthcare.gov](https://www.healthcare.gov/coverage-outside-open-enrollment/special-enrollment-period/). You have to show proof that your are moving from a foreign country to the US, and that you already had coverage in the foreign country, and the coverage can only take effect on the first day of a month.  However, there is no "minimum period of residency" before you are eligible.  You can call the phone number given on healthcare.gov for further guidance.